# jQuery UI Autocomplete doesn't display the results

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, oop, autocomplete

I'm trying to fill an autocomplete with the result of a mysql query and the options never show up, but I'm getting the json response correctly. I tried to change the z-index in my master css file and in the jquery-ui.css but it doesn't work.

This is my jquery function.

```
$('#tasklist').autocomplete({

    source: function(request, response) {

        $.ajax({

            url: 'pruebaproy.php',
            type: 'GET',
            data: {term: request.term},
            success: function(data) {

                response( $.map( data, function ( item ) {
                    return item;

            }));

            }

        });

    },
    minLength: 2,
    focus: function( event, ui ) {
        $('#tasklist').val( ui.item.nombre );
        return false;
    }

});
```

This is my PHP function that does the mysql query:

```
public function showTasks($term) {

    include 'Conexion.php';    
    $conectar = new Conexion();
    $arr_res = array();

    $consulta = "SELECT * FROM Actividades WHERE nombre LIKE '%".$term."%'";    

    if($stmt = $conectar->open()->query($consulta)) {

        while($row = $stmt->fetch_array(MYSQL_ASSOC)) {

            $task['id'] =  utf8_encode($row['idActividades']);
            $task['nombre'] =  utf8_encode($row['nombre']);
            $task['cat'] =  utf8_encode($row['parteAsoc']);

            array_push($arr_res, $task);

        }

        echo json_encode($arr_res);

    }

    $stmt->close();

}
```

And I call this function in my 'pruebaproy.php'

```
include('Proyecto.class.php');
$proyect = new Proyecto();


if(isset($_GET['term'])) {

    $proyect->showTasks(trim(strip_tags($_GET['term'])));

}
```

Comment: User dataType: "json", in the function of $ajax.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the datatype to 'json' on the ajax request, and place some alerts along the code to validate if you're getting there (for example inside the success).

Answer (score 0):

```
$( "#city" ).autocomplete({
source: function( request,response ) {
    $.ajax({
      url: "dtautocomplete.php",
      dataType: "json",
        data: {term: request.term},

      success: function( data) {

   response( data.myData );

}


    });
  },
  select: function( ) {

 $( "#city" ).attr("selectflag","1");

}
```

});

Php side

```
<?php


//die("sleeeeeeeeeeeeeeeppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppp");
$term=$_GET['term'];
$query="SELECT `RegionName`, `CenterLatitude`,`CenterLongitude` FROM `regioncentercoordinateslist` WHERE `RegionName` LIKE '".$term."%' AND `RegionName` NOT LIKE '%type%' LIMIT 10";          
      // echo $query;
       $data= mysql_query($query);

       //var_dump($data);die();
       $count=0;
       while($dat=mysql_fetch_array($data)) 
       {
         if($count>12)
         {break;}


        $tmpt1=$dat['CenterLatitude'];
          $tmpt2=$dat['CenterLongitude'];
          $tmpt=$tmpt1.",".$tmpt2;
         $city[] = array(
        'label' =>$dat['RegionName'],
        'value' => $tmpt

    );
    $city2[] = $dat['RegionName'];
    $options['myData'][] = array(
    'label' =>$dat['RegionName'],
        'value' => $dat['RegionName']
); 



    $name=$dat['RegionName'];
//  echo "<div>$name</div>";
        $count++;

       }



      echo json_encode($options);
        //flush();


 ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try utilizing [`._renderItem`](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#method-_renderItem) . See [Custom data and display](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#custom-data) "viewsource"

```
$('#tasklist').autocomplete({    
    source: function(request, response) {    
        $.ajax({    
            url: 'pruebaproy.php',
            type: 'GET',
            data: {term: request.term},
            success: function(data) {    
                response( $.map( data, function ( item ) {
                    return item
                })    
            }    
        });    
    },
    minLength: 2,
    focus: function( event, ui ) {
        $('#tasklist').val( ui.item.nombre );
        return false;
    }
}).autocomplete( "instance" )._renderItem = function( ul, item ) {
  return $( "<li>" )
    .append( "<a>" + item.id + "<br>" + item.cat + "</a>" )
    .appendTo( ul );
  };
});
```

---

```html
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>jQuery UI Autocomplete - Default functionality</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(function() {
    var availableTags = [
      "ActionScript",
      "AppleScript",
      "Asp",
      "BASIC",
      "C",
      "C++",
      "Clojure",
      "COBOL",
      "ColdFusion",
      "Erlang",
      "Fortran",
      "Groovy",
      "Haskell",
      "Java",
      "JavaScript",
      "Lisp",
      "Perl",
      "PHP",
      "Python",
      "Ruby",
      "Scala",
      "Scheme"
    ];
    $("#tags").autocomplete({
      source: availableTags
    }).autocomplete("instance")._renderItem = function(ul, item) {
      console.log(ul, item)
      return $("<li>")
        .append("<b style=color:orange;>" + item.label + "</b>")
        .appendTo(ul);
    };
    });
  </script>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="ui-widget">
    <label for="tags">Tags:</label>
    <input id="tags">
  </div>


</body>
```

Comment: Can describe "Doesn't work" ? , create stacksnippets, jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net to demonstrate ?

Comment: In the end, it was a z-index problem...

Thanks to everyone.